# Why do they put the fruit on the bottom?

Tags: fruit, yogurt

Why do they put fruit at the bottom of the yogurt? Why not at the top, or just mixed in?

Comment: They do sell yogurt with fruit mixed in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fruit will settle to the bottom of the yogurt during transit anyway; this way, it ends up neat and tidy and intentional. Many people mix it together just before eating if they prefer a more blended flavor.

Comment: Who eats the yogurt and then the fruit?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I know some of autistic people have issues with texture differences between things in their mouth at the same time and so eat each thing separate. But you're probably right that most people mix theirs.

Comment: When I have yoghurt with fruit at the bottom I do not mix but make sure I have some fruit as well as yoghurt on my spoon each bite. This only works if the pots are not too big.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I love how the yogurt gets ever fruitier with each layer carefully spooned off, and the final sugar bomb ;) With larger pots I will sometimes use the color gradient to make (very ephemeral) designs.

Comment: I've had yogurt with the fruit on top, might have been Mövenpick.

Answer (score 8):

At the time Dannon came to US, which was 1942, to appeal to the sweet tooth of Americans, fruit was added, but it was illegal at the time to mix anything with dairy. So they put it in the bottom to avoid this issue.

An excerpt from [this article](https://www.foodandwine.com/news/dannon-fruit-bottom-yogurt-history):

> Not only was adding fruit to the bottom a sweet answer to his American palate problem, but placing the fruit below the yogurt achieved another, perhaps less obvious goal. At the time, U.S. Food Safety standards for dairy production required that dairy products not be mixed with other things in it. Putting fruit on the top—or blending it—would have broken this requirement. By placing the fruit on the bottom and the cultured milk on top, Carasso was able to convince health authorities that it would be safe to package and eat due to "the low Ph, based on the acidity in fermentation that happens," according to Michael Neuwirth, a spokesman for Dannon.

Comment: interesting, do you have any link or reference to back that information up?

Comment: @Luciano I found this https://www.foodandwine.com/news/dannon-fruit-bottom-yogurt-history

Comment: @unbeatable101 great find! I edited and added to the answer. I actually believe this should be the accepted answer - I'm not sure OP is around to change it though